# Can you identify some parts on the Chinese New Year Temple Fair set #80105

Tags: part-identification

I'm trying to plan a smaller version of the Chinese New Year Temple Fair.

- Can you help me identify the parts used to make the plants on page 30
  of the instruction manual?
- Can you help me identify the 2 little curved parts used to make the
  roof on page 69?
- Can you help me identify the dragon-pole-thing and the tubular thing
  it's connected to on page 74.

Thanks.
[Link to Instructions](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/search#?search&text=80105%2520Chinese%2520New%2520Year%2520Temple%2520Fair%2520Chinese%2520Festivals)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. *[Part #24866 - Plate, Round 1 x 1 with Flower Edge (5 Petals).](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=24866&name=Plate,%20Round%201%20x%201%20with%20Flower%20Edge%20(5%20Petals)&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=C&C=5)*

   [image]
2. *[Part #32607 - Plant Plate, Round 1 x 1 with 3 Leaves.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32607&name=Plant%20Plate,%20Round%201%20x%201%20with%203%20Leaves&category=%5BPlant%5D#T=C)*

   [image]
3. *[Part #87580 - Plate, Modified 2 x 2 with Groove and 1 Stud in Center (Jumper).](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=87580&name=Plate,%20Modified%202%20x%202%20with%20Groove%20and%201%20Stud%20in%20Center%20(Jumper)&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C&C=36)*

   [image]
4. *[Part #19119 - Plant Flower Stem with Bar and 6 Stems.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=19119&name=Plant%20Flower%20Stem%20with%20Bar%20and%206%20Stems&category=%5BPlant%5D#T=C)*

   [image]
5. *[Part #49307 - Brick, Modified 1 x 1 x 2/3 No Studs, Curved Top.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=49307&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20x%202/3%20No%20Studs,%20Curved%20Top&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=C&C=4)*

   [image]
6. [Part #15070 - Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Tooth Vertical.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15070&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Tooth%20Vertical&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C&C=3)

   [image]
7. *[Part #36017- Minifigure, Weapon Sword Hilt with Dragon Head.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=36017&name=Minifigure,%20Weapon%20Sword%20Hilt%20with%20Dragon%20Head&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Weapon%5D#T=C&C=115)*

   [image]
8. [*Part #64644 - Minifigure, Utensil Telescope.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=64644&name=Minifigure,%20Utensil%20Telescope&category=%5BMinifigure,%20Utensil%5D#T=C)

   [image]